# What does these error about formating mean?

Tags: python, formatting

What does this error mean please? 
I have this code:

```
steps = np.loadtxt('par.in', unpack=True, usecols=[4])
maximum = np.loadtxt('par.in', unpack=True, usecols=[3])
minimum = np.loadtxt('par.in', unpack=True, usecols=[2])
a = "%0.2f" % (steps[1])
b = "%0.2f" % (maximum[1])
c = "%0.2f" % (minimum[1])


for i in np.arange (a,b,c):
    x, y, chi2, chi2r = np.loadtxt('omega_'+str("%0.2f" % i), unpack=True, usecols=[0, 2, 3, 4])
```

The error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "program.py",
>   line 34, in 
>       for i in np.arange (omega_min,omega_max,omega_krok): TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: a,b,c are string  not int type

Comment: `np.arrange()` expect 3 int params, you pass 3 str instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are pass parameter to `np.arange` which are str type, but you need to pass parameter as int/float type

```
steps = np.loadtxt('par.in', unpack=True, usecols=[4])
maximum = np.loadtxt('par.in', unpack=True, usecols=[3])
minimum = np.loadtxt('par.in', unpack=True, usecols=[2])
a = float("%0.2f" % (steps[1]))
b = float("%0.2f" % (maximum[1]))
c = float("%0.2f" % (minimum[1]))


for i in np.arange (a,b,c):
    x, y, chi2, chi2r = np.loadtxt('omega_'+str("%0.2f" % i), unpack=True, usecols=[0, 2, 3, 4])
```